# Grub to boot the Linux system, but I got stuck in this position `evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1`

Tags: linux

I am using Grub to boot the Linux system, but I got stuck in this position（`evm: HMAC attrs: 0x1` ） after booting up. May I ask if there is a problem with my `fstab`? Is the partition mounting of `fstab` sequential?

[image]

/etc/fstab:

```
 /dev/sda3   /         ext4  defaults   0 1
 /dev/sda1   /boot/efi vfat  umask=0077 0 0
 /dev/sda2   /boot     ext4  defaults   0 1
```

grub.cfg:

```
#Begin cfg
set default=0
set timeout=4

set root=(hd0,gpt3)

menuentry "GNU/Linux, Test-6.4.0-rt" {
    linux /bzImage rw root=/dev/sda3 rootdelay=90
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add details how exactly you installed the OS and, if applicable, add a link to the instructions you followed.

Comment: While not directly related, you should not use device like /dev/sda1 but use UUIDs, partUUIDs, or labels. Device may not be unique if you plug in a flash drive & it becomes sda as it does on my system. Also pass should be 0 for ESP as you cannot run fsck on FAT32 partitions & both /boot & / should be 1.

Comment: @Bodo I have added grub.cfg.

Comment: @oldfred thanks, I have modified.

Comment: My problem should be caused by the lack of initrd.

Comment: You do not mention which Linux. the grub boot stanza lines & parameters vary greatly with different distributions.

Comment: @oldfred a customized kernel，the version is 6.4.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the reason, the `initrd` is missing, just add it to `grub.cfg`.

```
 #Begin cfg
    set default=0
    set timeout=4

    set root=(hd0,gpt3)

    menuentry "GNU/Linux, Test-6.4.0-rt" {
        linux /bzImage rw root=/dev/sda3 noprompt
        initrd /initrd.img-6.4.0-rt8
    }
```